# Change Field Template using JSLink

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I am trying to replace a column's content with a javascript button in SharePoint. By following http://buildsharepointconcepts.blogspot.com/2018/05/go-to-workflow-initiation-form-on.html

This seems to be working fine.

```
    function StartWorkflowJsLink(overrideCtx) {
        /*If you have multiple list views on page better hard code this ListID Variable*/
        var ListID = overrideCtx.listName;
        var ItemGuid = '';
        /*Replace Template ID*/
        var TemplateID = '{D184A9EF-2DFB-4D67-828C-9C2FAF85B3B9}'; /* Get it from workflow start page URL. It will be changed everytime you republish the workflow.*/
        var SourceURL = window.location.href;
        var ItemID = overrideCtx.CurrentItem.ID;
        var webAbsoluteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
        var WFPageURL = '/wfsvc/9e06e2e17b974ce99c06ad30abf9229d/WFInitForm.aspx?';

        debugger;
        var workflowURL = webAbsoluteURL + WFPageURL + 'List=' + ListID + '&ID=' + ItemID + '&TemplateID=' + TemplateID + '&Source=' + SourceURL;
        var btnHTML = btnHTML = "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"GotoWFStartPage('" + workflowURL + "');\" value=\"Start Workflow\"></input>";
        return btnHTML;

    }
    function GotoWFStartPage(workflowURL) {


    window.location.href = workflowURL;

}


function registerListRenderer() {

    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        'Review': {
            'View': StartWorkflowJsLink
        }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
}

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerListRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');
```

However, I am trying to change the function to only display StartWorkflowJsLink if the Review column equals Start.

I tried following this article but it seems to not be working.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37332.sharepoint-2013-working-with-field-template-using-jslink.aspx

Any help that can be provided would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer below code. This should work for you.

Here we are checking value of `Review` field in `StartWorkflowJsLink` function. And if it is equal to `Start` then only our logic to create a button will be executed.

```
function StartWorkflowJsLink(overrideCtx) {
        if(overrideCtx.CurrentItem.Review == "Start"){
           /*If you have multiple list views on page better hard code this ListID Variable*/
              var ListID = overrideCtx.listName;
              var ItemGuid = '';
              /*Replace Template ID*/
              var TemplateID = '{D184A9EF-2DFB-4D67-828C-9C2FAF85B3B9}'; /* Get it from workflow start page URL. It will be changed everytime you republish the workflow.*/
              var SourceURL = window.location.href;
              var ItemID = overrideCtx.CurrentItem.ID;
              var webAbsoluteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
              var WFPageURL = '/wfsvc/9e06e2e17b974ce99c06ad30abf9229d/WFInitForm.aspx?';

              //debugger;
              var workflowURL = webAbsoluteURL + WFPageURL + 'List=' + ListID + '&ID=' + ItemID + '&TemplateID=' + TemplateID + '&Source=' + SourceURL;
              var btnHTML = btnHTML = "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"GotoWFStartPage('" + workflowURL + "');\" value=\"Start Workflow\"></input>";
              return btnHTML;
        }else{}
    }
    function GotoWFStartPage(workflowURL) {


    window.location.href = workflowURL;

}


function registerListRenderer() {

    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates.Fields = {
        'Review': {
            'View': StartWorkflowJsLink
        }
    };
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
}

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(registerListRenderer, 'clienttemplates.js');
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer based on the updated code in original post:

```
function StartWorkflowJsLink(overrideCtx) {
    var _value = overrideCtx.CurrentItem[overrideCtx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name];
    if (_value == 'Start')
    {
        /*If you have multiple list views on page better hard code this ListID Variable*/
        var ListID = overrideCtx.listName;
        var ItemGuid = '';
        /*Replace Template ID*/
        var TemplateID = '{D184A9EF-2DFB-4D67-828C-9C2FAF85B3B9}'; /* Get it from workflow start page URL. It will be changed everytime you republish the workflow.*/
        var SourceURL = window.location.href;
        var ItemID = overrideCtx.CurrentItem.ID;
        var webAbsoluteURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
        var WFPageURL = '/wfsvc/9e06e2e17b974ce99c06ad30abf9229d/WFInitForm.aspx?';

        //debugger;
        var workflowURL = webAbsoluteURL + WFPageURL + 'List=' + ListID + '&ID=' + ItemID + '&TemplateID=' + TemplateID + '&Source=' + SourceURL;
        var btnHTML = btnHTML = "<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"GotoWFStartPage('" + workflowURL + "');\" value=\"Start Workflow\"></input>";
        return btnHTML;
    }
    else
    return _value;
}
```

This will render a link only if the value of the Review field is "Start". Otherwise it will render just the text value of the Review field.

Comment: Hi Damjan, thanks for the reply. I updated my post to better explain what I am trying to do. Thanks for all of the help.

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Hi Damjan, unfortunately the script isnt working. Where does it specify the column name as "Review"?

Comment: This should return the name of the current field ("Review"): overrideCtx.CurrentFieldSchema.Name, but you could also hardcode it